# Permission error when trying to use chrome.fileSystem chooseEntry

Tags: google-chrome-app

When trying to use

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'openFile'
},chooseEntryCallback)`
```

on *Canary 28.0.1483.0* , I get the following error in the console:

> chrome.fileSystem is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.

I only require **read** access, and this is how my `permissions` option in the manifest file looks like:

```
"permissions": [
  {
    "fileSystem": []
  },
  "contextMenus",
  "clipboardWrite",
  "storage"
],
```

This works fine with *Stable 26.0.1410.64* so the question is whether there are some manifest permission changes which will need to be updated.

Note: Chrome running on Windows 8, and when opening the file via drag 'n drop it is opened without errors. So i'm guessing its some problem with `chooseEntry` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you already tried just "fileSystem" as a list item rather than a key in a dictionary. I made a sample with OSX 28.0.1484.0 based on your description (minus the other three permissions) and it worked as expected using either "fileSystem" or {"fileSystem": "write"}. It's possible you've found a bug that you can file at crbug.com.

Comment: @sowbug your comment solved my issue. I tried "fileSystem" as a list item and it worked on both stable & canary. What I had previously tried was {"fileSystem"} (which rendered the manifest invalid as I mistakenly left the curly brackets there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @sowbug's comment I fixed this issue by changing the `fileSystem` permission to a list item:

```
"permissions": [
  "fileSystem"
],
```

Edit:
To include the extended `write` permission:

```
"permissions": [
  "fileSystem",
  "fileSystem.write"
],
```